# How do I create a column to indicate whether each value in column 1 is appears in columns 2, 3, 4, etc.?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the example below, I add a new column "equal.to.master" indicating whether any of the columns whose names start with "col" have the same value as "master".

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  master = c(2,4,5,1,5),
  col.1 = 1:5, 
  col.2 = 5:1, 
  col.3 = c(NA, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
  irrelevant = 2:-2
)

df = mutate(df, equal.to.master = col.1 == master | col.2 == master | col.3 == master) 
df

  master col.1 col.2 col.3 irrelevant equal.to.master
1      2     1     5    NA          2              NA
2      4     2     4     4          1            TRUE
3      5     3     3     4          0           FALSE
4      1     4     2     4         -1           FALSE
5      5     5     1     4         -2            TRUE
```

Two questions:

1) How do I write this concisely without all the "|" symbols? There must be some "any"-like command I can use in conjunction with "starts_with" but I can't seem to format it correctly. Note that I can't simply grab all the columns because I want to ignore the one named "irrelevant."

2) How do I fix the code so that NA's are ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `apply()` -

```
df$equal.to.master <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  x[1] %in% x[2:3]
})

df

  master col.1 col.2 col.3 irrelevant equal.to.master
1      2     1     5    NA          2           FALSE
2      4     2     4     4          1            TRUE
3      5     3     3     4          0           FALSE
4      1     4     2     4         -1           FALSE
5      5     5     1     4         -2            TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `vectorized` approach with `rowSums`.  Create the logical index for column names that `startsWith` "col" ('nm1'), subset the dataset and compare with the 'master' column using `==`, get the `rowSums` and check if it is greater than 0

```
nm1 <-  startsWith(names(df), "col")
df$equal.to.master <- rowSums(df[nm1]  == df$master, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
df$equal.to.master
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Also, if any `NA` in a row needs to return `NA`, then remove the `na.rm = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
rowSums(df[nm1]  == df$master, na.rm = FALSE) > 0
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[nm1], `==`, df$master))
```